# Find the Longest Gap in a schedule

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, job-scheduling

I am trying to find the largest gap between two tasks that doesn't overlap with any other task. given `n` tasks with their start and end time. We are also given a start time and and end time for the process. The largest gap should be between start and end.

I have came up with an algorithm where I sort the tasks based on their ending time in ascending order and then use a sweeping line method to check the last compatible job with job i (if there are any) and calculate the gap from there. However, my algorithm is failing in a lot of cases. Any help?

Python Code:

```
largestgap = timedelta(0)
for i in range(len(tasks)):
    s1 = tasks[i].start
    e1 = tasks[i].end
    if s1 > start and s1 < end:
        s2 = tasks[i-1].start
        e2 = tasks[i-1].end
        if s1 > e2:
            if e2 < start:
                largestgap = max(largestgap, s1 - start)
            else:
                largestgap = max(largestgap, s1 - e2)

return str(largestgap.seconds)
```

Comment: Since this looks like a homework question, just a hint: come up with a data structure that represents the sequence of time intervals covered and not covered by a task. Enter the tasks one by one and then read off the largest gap.

Comment: @Henry This isn't Hw. I am practicing algorithm questions on online judges so that's all. Can you perhaps let me know what that data structure is?

Comment: For example a sorted list of disjoint covered time intervals. When entering a new task there are several cases: add a new interval, extend an existing interval, merge two or more intervals into one and possibly also extend it.

Comment: @Henry But I don't see why my code doesn't work here though. What is wrong with my algorithm with sorting?

Comment: Analyse one of the cases where it fails in detail.